# Find the locus of the middle point of the intercept on the line y=x+c made by the lines 2x+3y=5 & 2x+3y=8, c being a parameter?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Here's my shot:
since the two lines are parallel, I figured that the middle point should be equidistant from the parallel lines,so using distance formula:-

$ \frac{2x+3y-5}{\sqrt{13}}=\frac{2x+3y-8}{\sqrt{13}}$

I get, $4x+6y-13=0$(considering one equation +ve and other -ve)
which seems to be the right answer,
but my question is, is there any other standard method to solve this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locus traced by all the midpoints is just the line in the middle: $2x+3y=\frac{13}{2}$ or $4x+6y-13=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve the following system:
$$2x+3y=\frac{5+8}{2}$$ and $$y=x+c.$$

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid it's wrong. The correct answer is only relevant to the first part.

Comment: @Abdullah I don't agree with you. See please better what we need to find.

Comment: to find the locus why would we need to solve the system of equations, that would give us the point right? Correct me if I'm wrong Michael, much appreciated.

Comment: @Abdullah  We need to find intersection points of the locus with the line $y=x+c$. See please better your problem.

Comment: I see, but the answer doesn't matches it.

Comment: @Abdullah  If you'll solve the system, which I wrote, you'll got the answer.